# Eclipse cross-compile... how can I do that?

Tags: c, windows, linux, eclipse, cross-compiling

I am developing on a Windows machine using Eclipse in C code.
All the files are physically located on a Linux server.
I am using Eclipse only for editing and code browsing.
When I want to compile, I open a terminal and telnet to the Linux server from which I call a file that sets up few variables and eventually invoke a "make" command.

The server is pretty busy.. I would then like to be able to compile locally [and then just ftp these executable files back to the Linux machine so that I can execute them.. unless Eclipse can do that on its own :) ].... any idea how can that be done? I am not well versed in Eclipse or OS usage.... so if you could answer and explain what I should do.. I would really appreciate...

I changed the Build Command under Project Properties menu by just calling the script file on the server I usually invoke to compile... That looked fairly simple.. well... that was too good to be true... and of course.. it didn't work! I am getting this error if I use the default "make" (Cannot run program "make": Launching failed).... while getting (Cannot run program "T:\compile": Launching failed) if I try to invoke my script file that I use to compile...

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at running a [crosstool-ng](http://ymorin.is-a-geek.org/dokuwiki/projects/crosstool) setup on your windows box inside [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/).  And then have eclipse use that compiler.  This will allow you to develop for your target Linux platform easily.

Here's some [slides](http://www.appinf.com/download/EclipseEmbeddedLinuxSlides.pdf)

It sounds like you're developing for a desktop/server platform, so you'll have to make sure you set up your crosstool-ng with the same versions of standard libs as your server has (libc, libstdc++, etc).  You also want to make sure your crosstool-ng has the same version of gcc as the target as well.

If you don't want to mess with getting all that setup, you could always install Linux as a virtual machine on your windows box and work inside there.